# Coloring svg using javascript when clicking an arrow to go to the next slide

Tags: javascript, svg, tabs, fill

I have to color SVG when I press red square to change slide, can someone help me?

I can color SVG when I hit, but when I click the red square to go to the next slide I have no idea how to change the color of the SVG so that it matches colored white.

So the final result should be that when I click on the red square the slide changes, SVG turns white together with the pink background

```js
// Script written by @hamzadhamiya for @bloggerever.
// http://bloggerever.com

$(function () {
    $.FindContainer = function () {
        $('.tab-content>div').each(function findcontent() {
            var newindex = $('.activetab').index();
            var newheight = $('.activetab').height();
            $('.tab-content').animate({
                'height': newheight+20
            }, 100);
            var otherindex = $(this).index();
            var substractindex = otherindex - newindex;
            var currentwidth = $('.multipletab').width();
            var newpositions = substractindex * currentwidth;
            $(this).animate({
                'left': newpositions
            });
        });
    };
    $.FindId = function () {
        $('.tab-content>div').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == $('.active').attr('id')) {
                $('.tab-content>div').removeClass('activetab');
                $(this).addClass('activetab');
            }
        });
    };
    $('.tab-buttons>span').first().addClass('active');
    $('.tab-content>div').each(function () {
        var activeid = $('.active').attr('id');
        if ($(this).attr('id') == activeid) {
            $(this).addClass('activetab');
        }
        var currentheight = $('.activetab').height();
        var currentwidth = $('.multipletab').width();
        var currentindex = $(this).index();
        var currentposition = currentindex * currentwidth;
        $(this).css({
            'left': currentposition,
                'width': currentwidth - 40,
                'padding': '10px 20px'
        });
        $(this).attr('data-position', currentposition);
        $('.tab-content').css('height', currentheight+20);
    });
    $('.tab-buttons>span').click(function () {

        $('.tab-buttons>span').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currentid = $('.active').attr('id');
        $.FindId();
        $.FindContainer();
    });
    $('.next').click(function () {
        var activetabindex = $('.activetab').index() + 1;
        var containers = $('.tab-content>div').length;
        if (containers == activetabindex) {
            $('.tab-buttons>span').removeClass('active');
            $('.tab-buttons>span').first().addClass('active');
            var currentid = $('.active').attr('id');
            $.FindId();
            $.FindContainer();
        } else {
            var currentopen = $('.active').next();
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            currentopen.addClass('active');
            $.FindId();
            $.FindContainer();
        }
    });
  $('.prev').click(function(){
    var activetabindex = $('.activetab').index();
        if (activetabindex == 0) {
            $('.tab-buttons>span').removeClass('active');
            $('.tab-buttons>span').last().addClass('active');
            var currentid = $('.active').attr('id');
            $.FindId();
            $.FindContainer();
        } else {
            var currentopen = $('.active').prev();
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            currentopen.addClass('active');
            $.FindId();
            $.FindContainer();
        }
  });
});

//script che colora il tabs tessuti
document.getElementById("linkTessuti1").classList.add("colorebianco")
function onclickWhite1() {
    var color1=document.getElementById("linkTessuti1");
    color1.classList.add("colorebianco");
    var rimuovicolor2=document.getElementById("linkTessuti2");
    rimuovicolor2.classList.remove("colorebianco");
    var rimuovicolor3=document.getElementById("linkTessuti3");
    rimuovicolor3.classList.remove("colorebianco");
}
function onclickWhite2() {
    var color2=document.getElementById("linkTessuti2");
    color2.classList.add("colorebianco");
    var rimuovicolor1=document.getElementById("linkTessuti1");
    rimuovicolor1.classList.remove("colorebianco");
    var rimuovicolor3=document.getElementById("linkTessuti3");
    rimuovicolor3.classList.remove("colorebianco");
}
function onclickWhite3() {
    var color3=document.getElementById("linkTessuti3");
    color3.classList.add("colorebianco");
    var rimuovicolor1=document.getElementById("linkTessuti1");
    rimuovicolor1.classList.remove("colorebianco");
    var rimuovicolor2=document.getElementById("linkTessuti2");
    rimuovicolor2.classList.remove("colorebianco");
}
```

```css
.multipletab{
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.tab-buttons{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:2px solid #666;
}
.tab-buttons>span{
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 20%;
  background:green;
}
.tab-buttons>span.active{
  background:pink;
  position:relative;
}
.tab-content{
position:relative;
}
.tab-content>div{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.tab-nav>span{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
}
.tab-nav>span.next{
  right:10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.tab-nav>span.prev{
  left:10px;
  background-color: red;

}

.colorebianco {
  fill: #ffffff!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Sliding Multiple Tabs with Arrow navigation</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class='multipletab'>
    
  <div class='tab-buttons'>
    
    <span id='content1'>
       <svg onclick="onclickWhite1()" id="linkTessuti1" version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"               x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 80 80" enable-background="new 0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">   
            <path d="M40,16c13.23,0,24,10.77,24,24S53.23,64,40,64S16,53.23,16,40S26.77,16,40,16 M40,15c-13.81,0-25,"/>
       </svg>
            </span>
    <span id='content2'>
       <svg onclick="onclickWhite2()" id="linkTessuti2" version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"                 x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 80 80" enable-background="new 0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">   
            <path d="M40,16c13.23,0,24,10.77,24,24S53.23,64,40,64S16,53.23,16,40S26.77,16,40,16 M40,15c-13.81,0-25,"/>
       </svg>
    </span>
    <span id='content3'>
            <svg onclick="onclickWhite3()" id="linkTessuti3" version="1.1" id="Livello_1"               xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 80 80" enable-background="new 0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">   
            <path d="M40,16c13.23,0,24,10.77,24,24S53.23,64,40,64S16,53.23,16,40S26.77,16,40,16 M40,15c-13.81,0-25,"/>
       </svg>
    </span>
        <span id='content4'>
            <svg onclick="onclickWhite4()" id="linkTessuti4" version="1.1" id="Livello_1"       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 80 80" enable-background="new 0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">   
            <path d="M40,16c13.23,0,24,10.77,24,24S53.23,64,40,64S16,53.23,16,40S26.77,16,40,16 M40,15c-13.81,0-25,"/>
       </svg>
            </span>
    <span id='content5'>
         <svg onclick="onclickWhite5()" id="linkTessuti5" version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 80 80" enable-background="new 0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">   
            <path d="M40,16c13.23,0,24,10.77,24,24S53.23,64,40,64S16,53.23,16,40S26.77,16,40,16 M40,15c-13.81,0-25,"/>
       </svg>
    </span>
    <!--add more button right after it with same id attribute of that container. Make sure to use span tag.-->
  </div>
  <div class='tab-content'>
    
    <div id='content1'>
      THE CONTENT OF FIRST TAB.THE CONTENT OF FIRST TAB.THE
    </div>
    <div id='content2'>
      This is Second Containter.This is Second Containter.This
    </div>
    <div id='content3'>
      THE CONTENT OF 3RD CONTAINER GOES HERETHE CONTENT OF
    </div>
        <div id='content4'>
      THE CONTENT OF 4RD CONTAINER GOES HERETHE CONTENT OF
    </div>
    <div id='content5'>
      THE CONTENT OF 5RD CONTAINER GOES HERETHE CONTENT OF
    </div>
    <!--add more container right after it with same id attribute of that button. Make sure to use div tag.-->
  </div>
  <div class='tab-nav'>
  <span class='next'></span>
    <span class='prev'></span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error you got when creating this question was `Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code`... Maybe don't hack that and actually provide the code?

Comment: sorry @Dominik I'm new in this forum now I have correct the post, you can help me please?

Comment: Tanks @Dominik can you help me also with the code?
I started with javascript recently and i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specifically set the circle to white (class `.colorebianco`).  Instead just add a CSS rule that makes the circle white if it is in the `.active` span.

```
.tab-buttons>span.active path {
  fill: #ffffff!important;
}
```

Then everything works automatically for you.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, thank you very much.
If i can support you in any way within the form please tell me, i am new and i don't know how it works.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck with your project!